# Convert EG-Style to Proc template or otherwise

Tags: sas

I created a new Style in Enterprise Guide with the style manager.
After creating, I can use that style when working with enterprise guide, that is no problem.

But now i want to build a stored process which uses the exact same style when calling the STP from server via a browser. Our server only uses the the default style, I can not replace this style or upload a custom style (Because then i would also change the style for other people working with the server). If i worked with stps in browser, I used proc template to generate a style. So I am looking for a automatic way to "translate" an eg-style to a proc template, so i can add the style to a report in the code of the stored process.

I am looking for a way to build it once, and then "translate" one automatically to the other without writing complete code again, because the style is very extensive.

An option "Convert EG-Style to proc template code" or something similar would be nice, but I could not find it.

Does somebody know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: When you created a new style, how did you do it in Style Manager?  Did you create a new external style, or based on an existing one?  When you're in the Style Manager, do you see something in the "URL" field for that style?  What kind of code are you using to use this style - PROC REPORT, TABULATE, etc.?

Comment: You can export the style as a CSS Style Sheet. Depending on your output type many can use this to define styles.

Comment: @Joe: For the start i create it based on a existing one, just for testing. Sas stores it locally on my pc, if i run a programm inside the EG it applies the style. If i copy the stylesheet to the server and apply it inside the STP with a put statement, it uses the standard style anyway when calling the STP in the browser (Standard style seems to be higher priorisized inside the STP-Application portal). So i wanted to use a proc template, because i know then it would use the given style, not the standard, but i dont want to write it at all by hand in the proctemplate.

Comment: @Reeza: Yes, i imported the style to the server, but the STP used standard style anyway. I could see in the developer tools that the new css and it styles are there in the browser, but the standard styles are higher priorisized and overwriting my custom style.

Comment: @kl78 Locally yes, but still you have a physical .css file, right?  That *is* the code.  You can point directly to it, don't need to import it or anything - use `cssstyle` option instead of `style`.